# javascript/jQuery - What is jQuery.fx?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have seen `$.fx.step. backgroundPosition = function(fx) {...}` in some javascript snippet. I can't find much infomation about `$.fx`.

Can anyone provide a link to some detailed tutorial on `$.fx` ?

PS:
I have read this: http://onwebdev.blogspot.com/2011/02/jquery-fx-object.html

But as a javascript newbie, I didn't quite get the point of it.

Comment: In your second snippet, `fx` is just a parameter to the function, it's not anything special.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short: `fx` is the basis of all [jQuery effects](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) like `.animate`, `.hide`, etc.

Code like the one you posted is meant to extend `jQuery.fx`.

Comment: *benknowscode.wordpress.com is no longer available. - The authors have deleted this site.*

Answer (score 1):

You can see more details about $.fx [**HERE**](http://docs.jquery.com/Release%3ajQuery_1.2/Effects)

A new jQuery plugin that supports animating CSS colors of elements by using the new jQuery.fx.step.

Answer (score 0):

[**Here**](http://onwebdev.blogspot.com/2011/02/jquery-fx-object.html) is stated, that **`fx`** object is declared as follows:

```
fx: function( elem, options, prop ) {
        this.options = options;
        this.elem = elem;
        this.prop = prop;

        if ( !options.orig ) {
            options.orig = {};
        }
}
```

read more that link.